# Best way to handle Integer overflow in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, integer, overflow

Handling integer overflow is a common task, but what's the best way to handle it in C#? Is there some syntactic sugar to make it simpler than with other languages? Or is this really the best way?

```
int x = foo();
int test = x * common;
if(test / common != x)
    Console.WriteLine("oh noes!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("safe!");
```

Comment: best way is to prevent in first place

Comment: Sure, but that's a different question from the one presented here. Handling it and preventing it are seperate (related of course) discussions.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I haven't needed to use this often, but you can use the [checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) keyword:

```
int x = foo();
int test = checked(x * common);
```

Will result in a runtime exception if overflows.  From MSDN:

> In a checked context, if an expression produces a value that is
>   outside the range of the destination type, the result depends on
>   whether the expression is constant or non-constant. Constant
>   expressions cause compile time errors, while non-constant expressions
>   are evaluated at run time and raise exceptions.

I should also point out that there is another C# keyword, `unchecked`, which of course does the opposite of `checked` and ignores overflows.  You might wonder when you'd ever use `unchecked` since it appears to be the default behavior.  Well, there is a C# compiler option that defines how expressions outside of `checked` and `unchecked` are handled: [/checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/checked-compiler-option).  You can set it under the advanced build settings of your project.

If you have a lot of expressions that need to be checked, the simplest thing to do would actually be to set the `/checked` build option.  Then any expression that overflows, unless wrapped in `unchecked`, would result in a runtime exception.

Comment: Why is the default behavior is unchecked? Is there any performance concerns on using checked?

Comment: @KFL "Because checking for overflow takes time, the use of unchecked code in situations where there is no danger of overflow might improve performance. However, if overflow is a possibility, a checked environment should be used."  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx.  I also believe that the default is unchecked because it parallels the C / C++ behavior.

Comment: There are cases where overflow is useful, for instance the TCP sequence number. An unsigned int just wraps around to zero, so all that's needed is the increment operator.

Comment: Does unchecked produce same results in case of overflow on all machines??

Comment: Updated url reference for 'checked' - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: This is useful for unexpected overflow. Be aware of the added overhead of the exception if overflows are common.

Answer (score 22):

Try the following

```
int x = foo();
try {
  int test = checked (x * common);
  Console.WriteLine("safe!");
} catch (OverflowException) {
  Console.WriteLine("oh noes!");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The best way is as Micheal Said - use Checked keyword.
This can be done as :

```
int x = int.MaxValue;
try   
{
    checked
    {
        int test = x * 2;
        Console.WriteLine("No Overflow!");
    }
}
catch (OverflowException ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Overflow Exception caught as: " + ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You need to format your code (insert 4 spaces prior to it and the site will automatically pick up the formatting and syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, the **simplest** way is the **best** way. I can't think a better way to write what you wrote, but you can short it to:

```
int x = foo();

if ((x * common) / common != x)
    Console.WriteLine("oh noes!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("safe!");
```

Note that I didn't remove the `x` variable because it'd be foolish to call the `foo()` three times.

Comment: Now I wonder if the compiler would ever optimize that expression away entirely?

Comment: USefull, unless of course you are planning on using the result (x*common), in that case your shortening would require the calculation to be done twice ...

Comment: What if common == 0?

Answer (score 4):

Old thread, but I just ran into this. I didn't want to use exceptions. What I ended up with was:

```
long a = (long)b * (long)c;
if(a>int.MaxValue || a<int.MinValue)
    do whatever you want with the overflow
return((int)a);
```

Comment: This won't work. `int.MaxValue + 1` gives you -2147483648 or `int.MinValue`. so `a` can never be larger than MaxValue or smaller than MinValue. Think of numbers as a line like this: `-2147483648, -2147483647, ... 0 ...  2147483646, 2147483647` when you go over the max value, it flows back to the smallest.

Comment: you missed the fact that he/she converted to long before checking against the bounds of the int. so it would work as long it doesnt overflow the long.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ran into this far after the fact, and it mostly answered my question, but for my particular case (in the event anyone else has the same requirements), I wanted anything that would overflow the positive value of a signed int to just settle at `int.MaxValue`:

```
int x = int.MaxValue - 3;
int someval = foo();

try
{
   x += someval;
}

catch (OverflowException)
{
   x = int.MaxValue;
}
```

Comment: The exception wouldn't get thrown unless you compile with ```/checked```, or use the ```checked``` keyword, correct?