# Why does assigning an a value greater than an int to an int not throw an exception by default?

Tags: c#, .net

I used ILSpy to reflect into the `LINQ's` Sum method and noticed that it just does a `foreach` with the `checked` keyword.  But if an `int` has a defined maximum and you try to go over it, why doesn't it throw an error by default. Assuming you don't use `Sum` and you do your own `foreach` without `checked`, you will not get an exception, it will just give you a garbage value if you go over the maximum `int` value, but I don't see the reason why this is not just default behavior.  If you need something bigger than an `int`, then don't use an `int`.

Comment: You can enable checked arithmetic in your project settings. I do that for almost all of my projects.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - OK, I never knew this. Thanks for pointing this out, but why still isn't this default behavior?  From my own perspective, if I know a value is going to exceed the maximum of an int, I will use something bigger.

Comment: One place where `unchecked` is useful is `GetHashCode` where it doesn't really matter if the `int` overflow. It just need to be fast and fairly accurate. `Equals` is used anyway to determine if the two objects are really equal if `GetHashCode` returns the same value. http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/284240

Comment: @CodesInChaos - And if you do it in project settings, does it do it for ints, shorts, etc?  Is there a valid reason why you would want to throw an error for an arithmetic overflow for an int, but not a short?

Comment: performance reasons?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259408/why-doesnt-c-sharp-use-arithmetic-overflow-checking-by-default

Comment: @NDJ - I actually did a search for this and didn't find it. Thanks.

Comment: See also the thread [Why don't languages raise errors on integer overflow by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103654/), a near duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Checked operations are significantly slower than unchecked:

```
const int startVal = Int32.MaxValue - 1000000;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
int i = startVal;
while (i < Int32.MaxValue)
{
    unchecked
    {
        i++;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Unchecked: " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks");

i = startVal;
sw.Restart();
while (i < Int32.MaxValue)
{
    checked
    {
        i++;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Checked: " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks");
```

Result:

> Unchecked: 241 ticks
>   Checked: 1992 ticks

So using checked results in a performance hit, and since overflow is relatively rare (who actually counts up to `Int32.MaxValue`?), C# uses unchecked by default.

Comment: But since it won't matter in 99% of the code it'd be better to enable it by default and only disable it selectively.

Comment: Didn't think it would actually be that much? What did you run those metrics on?

Comment: Standard .NET 4 console application in release mode

Comment: Sure, but your code example has the disadvantage that in one case an exception is raised and dealt with by the `catch` block, while in the other case time is not wasted on that. Maybe you should change to `while (i != int.MaxValue)` and drop the `try`-`catch`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: oops, didn't spot that. I've edited & re-ran the program.

Comment: @thecoop - When I run it, I get `7092ms for unchecked` and `6891ms for checked`.  I'm just running it on an `i7 CPU at 2.9GHz with 8 GB Ram on a 64 bit OS`

Comment: Ok, I ran it in LinqPad first and then in VS and `checked` rand somewhat slower.

Comment: @Xaisoft: were you running in debug or release mode? Was the debugger attached?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't see the reason why this is not just default behavior

There may be costs involved in performing such checks - either checking of processor flags, or (if using a larger register internally) checking the upper contents of a register. And basic assignment can be an operation occurring inside the tightest of loops - the costs could be appreciable, and not everyone should have to pay.

So you get to choose whether you want those checks to occur.

Comment: OK, That makes sense, but I am not hardware expert, but with the advance of hardware today, does this really matter any more?  That maybe a stupid statement, but like I said, I am not a hardware expert and I am not sure how much performance we are talking about.

Comment: Well, @thecoop seems to be doing a good job of giving you benchmarks - and as I say, such basic assignment happens a *lot*, and I'd be willing to wager that in 99.9999% of cases, there's never any *risk* that an overflow will occur.