# How can I convert a signed integer into an unsigned integer?

Tags: c#, integer, uint

The piece of code is like:-

```
int x = -24;  
uint y = (uint) x;  
Console.WriteLine("*****" + y + "********");  
// o/p is *****4294967272********
```

Why this type of behavior in C#, Detailed elaboration would be helpful. Thankyou all.

Comment: Why are you asking how to convert an `int` to a `uint` when you already have the code that does it? What are you asking?

Comment: Have you tried using Convert.ToUInt32() inbuilt function?

Comment: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Negative numbers (like `-24`) are represented as a *binary complement*, see

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

for details. In your case

```
   24     = 00000000000000000000000000011000
  ~24     = 11111111111111111111111111100111
  ~24 + 1 = 11111111111111111111111111101000 =
          = 4294967272
```

When casting `int` to `uint` be careful, since `-24` is *beyond* `uint` range (which `[0..uint.MaxValue]`) you can have `OverflowException` being thrown. A safier implementation is

```
 int x = -24;  
 uint y = unchecked((uint) x); // do not throw OverflowException exception
```

Comment: Correct. Works as intended.

Comment: The OP's code worked without the `unchecked` keyword.

Comment: @Enigmativity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259408/why-doesnt-c-sharp-use-arithmetic-overflow-checking-by-default

Comment: 4294967295 is the max uint value can take and since 4294967272 is lower than that number it CANNOT give OverflowException so there is no need for `unchecked`. Actually casting from int to uint will never get OverflowException...

Comment: @sotn: please, carry out an easy experiment: `int x = -24; uint y = checked((uint) x);` and see the `OverflowException`. Its `-24` that's beyond `uint.MinValue` (which is `0`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko what I meant was, why to use unchecked at all (in this case) since the default option for checked/unchecked is determined by compiler option? But if it would be the opposite case (casting from uint to int, that's a different story I think)

Comment: Well It doesn't give OverflowException from uint to int either (without using checked/unchecked) :D I guess you're right..

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Are you saying that without the `checked` or `unchecked` then the behaviour is ambiguous (base on the compiler setting), but since the OP wants the cast to succeed then `unchecked` should be used?

Comment: @sotn: imagine that you've developed the routine, tested it a pass to be build as a part of an industrial solution which has its own settings, make file, complier settings… You *don't* have the error, but users *do*, a-a-a-a!

Comment: @sotn: if you want `OverflowException` on the cast *reversed*, i.e. `uint -> int`, try this: `uint y = 3000000000u; int x = checked((int) y);` since *3 billions* is within `uint` range but out of `int` one.

Comment: Yes guys, you're right. I missed some points. At first I thought like the most important bit in 32 bits is used for un/signed flag whereas the other 31 bits are used for the value and thought that the numbers greater than 2^31 cannot be handled by `int` data type since it will require to not use that most important bit flag and I thought that the numbers between 0 and -(2^31) are ok to convert bidirectionally since it doesn't "compromise" that sign flag. I don't know if it makes sense but I was wrong :)

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko, this is the detailed answer I needed. Thankyou again.

Answer (score 11):

There are few ways to convert `int` to `uint`

```
int x;
```

**Technique #1**

```
uint y = Convert.ToUInt32(x);
```

**Technique #2**

```
uint y = checked((uint) x);
```

**Technique #3**

```
uint y = unchecked((uint) x);
```

**Technique #4**

```
uint y = (uint) x;
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what's going on and what the differences are.

Answer (score -2):

Try the below code

```
int x = -24;  
Console.WriteLine("*****" + Convert.ToUInt32(x) + "********");
```