# In C# is it possible to convert an integer to an unsinged integer without a typecast?

Tags: c#, exception, type-conversion, unsigned, signed

**Is it possible to convert an integer into an unsinged integer without the need of explicit typecasts?**

I have the following code -

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        int num1 = -33;
        uint num2 = Convert.ToUInt32 (num1);
        Console.WriteLine (num2);
    }
}
```

It throws me the error -

> System.OverflowException has been thrown.
>
> Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32

I don't want to use explicit typecasting. Is it possible this way?

The question is not a duplicate of the question [How can I convert a signed integer into an unsigned integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548277/how-can-i-convert-a-signed-integer-into-an-unsigned-integer) As I have specifically mentioned that I want to know is it possible without using explicit typecasting or not?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162160/discussion-on-question-by-jonita-gandhi-in-c-is-it-possible-to-use-convert-toui).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if it is possible without explicit typecasting?

The short answer is: **Nope**.

> I want to know the reason of existence of the function Convert.ToUInt32()

Answer: Someone at microsoft found it helpful and created that. Others found it helpful/easy to use and used it. I guess we won't find the concrete reason for implementing that function.

### Further information on this topic:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42548376/4992212) states 4 possibilities. 
Each of them include a typecast. I don't know another built-in feature to convert uint to int. [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21668055/4992212) nicely explains the converting of uint->int and it's pitfalls.

> (UltraShort)**Summary**: You have to take care of *overflows*.

You should have a look at [checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) and [unchecked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) keywords when dealing with unsigned types.

### TypeConversion

Depending on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/conversion-operators) there are 4 methods of TypeConversion.

- Implicit
- Explicit
- User-defined conversions using [conversion oerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/conversion-operators).
- Conversions with helüer classes (Like the Convert class)

### The usecase of Convert.ToInt32() / Convert.ToUInt32()

Codesample for **ToInt32()** is taken from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/303w38b8(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
float[] values= { Single.MinValue, -1.38e10f, -1023.299f, -12.98f,
                  0f, 9.113e-16f, 103.919f, 17834.191f, Single.MaxValue };
int result;

foreach (float value in values)
{
   try {
      result = Convert.ToInt32(value);
      Console.WriteLine("Converted the {0} value {1} to the {2} value {3}.",
                        value.GetType().Name, value, result.GetType().Name, result);
   }
   catch (OverflowException) {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of the Int32 type.", value);
   }   
}                                 
// The example displays the following output:
//    -3.40282346638529E+38 is outside the range of the Int32 type.
//    -13799999488 is outside the range of the Int32 type.
//    Converted the Double value -1023.29901123047 to the Int32 value -1023.
//    Converted the Double value -12.9799995422363 to the Int32 value -13.
//    Converted the Double value 0 to the Int32 value 0.
//    Converted the Double value 9.11299983940444E-16 to the Int32 value 0.
//    Converted the Double value 103.918998718262 to the Int32 value 104.
//    Converted the Double value 17834.19140625 to the Int32 value 17834.
//    3.40282346638529E+38 is outside the range of the Int32 type.
```

Codesample for Convert.**ToUInt(Int32)** also taken from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s1a7zd61(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int[] numbers = { Int32.MinValue, -1203, 0, 121, 1340, Int32.MaxValue };
uint result;
foreach (int number in numbers)
{
   try {
      result = Convert.ToUInt32(number);
      Console.WriteLine("Converted the {0} value {1} to the {2} value {3}.",
                        number.GetType().Name, number,
                        result.GetType().Name, result);
   }
   catch (OverflowException) {
      Console.WriteLine("The {0} value {1} is outside the range of the UInt32 type.",
                        number.GetType().Name, number);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    The Int32 value -2147483648 is outside the range of the UInt32 type.
//    The Int32 value -1203 is outside the range of the UInt32 type.
//    Converted the Int32 value 0 to the UInt32 value 0.
//    Converted the Int32 value 121 to the UInt32 value 121.
//    Converted the Int32 value 1340 to the UInt32 value 1340.
//    Converted the Int32 value 2147483647 to the UInt32 value 2147483647.
```

Answer (score 1):

As request by the OP comment:

```
//Sample inputs
string str = "15";
bool b = false;
int i = 15;
double d = 14.5;
object o = str;
object oi = i;

//These are not valid
//uint ustr = (uint)str; 
//uint ub = (uint)b;

//This is valid at compile time but throw a run time exception
//uint uo = (uint)o;
//uint uoi = (uint)oi;

//These are valid
uint ustr = Convert.ToUInt32(str);
uint ub = Convert.ToUInt32(b);
uint uo = Convert.ToUInt32(o);
uint uoi2 = Convert.ToUInt32(oi);

//both ways are valid
uint ud = (uint)d;
uint ud2 = Convert.ToUInt32(d);
uint ui = (uint)i;
uint ui2 = Convert.ToUInt32(i);

//Some inputs can't be converted by either way (casting may be possible but result in wrong values)
string str2 = "Bananas";
int i2 = -15;
```