# Is it guaranteed that outer checked/unchecked context influences the behavior of lambdas created inside it?

Tags: c#, lambda, language-lawyer, unchecked-conversion

Assuming [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259408/why-doesnt-c-sharp-use-arithmetic-overflow-checking-by-default) arithmetic overflow (not)checking, the following code

```
Action<Int32[]> action;

checked
{
    action = array =>
        Console.WriteLine(array[0] + array[1]);
}

var items = new[]
{
    Int32.MaxValue,
    Int32.MaxValue
};
action(items);
```

will result in

> System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow..

If we set project settings to [/checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx), and replace `checked {` with `unchecked {`, the exception won't be thrown.

So, can we rely on this behavior, or is it safer to `array => unchecked (array[0] + array[1])`?

Comment: You want a warranty that the C# compiler does not have any bugs??   The github site lists *ten thousand* issues, a third of which are still open.  Just happened to run into [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18446) when I looked just now :)

Comment: @HansPassant As far as I can see there is no bug here - everything works fine and quite logically. But whether one can rely on this behavior as a standard is what troubles me. Specification mentioned in [@InBeetween's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43225470/3745022) is a bit vague and whether lambdas are guaranteed to be affected or not is still slightly doubtful.

Comment: Come back when it doesn't work and you have a concrete problem to show us, SO is always around.

Comment: @HansPassant I do not  exactly agree that this question is off-topic. It is just more of a language-lawyer question, than a specific "my code doesn't work" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last officially published C# spec, it says the following:

> 8.11 (...) The checked statement causes all expressions in the block to be evaluated in a checked context, and the unchecked statement causes all expressions in the block to be evaluated in an unchecked context. (...)

I'd say pretty confidently that `action` will always be evaluated in a checked/ unchecked context which is the current behavior you are seeing and I wouldn't expect this to change in the future.

To expand a little more on my answer, if you check the compiled code, you'll see that `Console.WriteLine(array[0] + array[1])` inside the `checked` statement is actually compiled as the equivalent of `Console.WriteLine(checked (array[0] + array[1]))` so there is really no need to do it yourself, the compiler will do it anyways.

Comment: Well, it seems that we can take `8.11` literally, so with lambda's body being in checked context it should be affected by it. Thanks, though I would probably continue to apply `(un)checked` inside the lambda - it should be reliable for sure and it is more localized/shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that `checked` and `unchecked` change the *instructions that the compiler emits*. E.g. there are two (actually more) variants of an `add` instruction in IL, where one variant *ignores* overflow and the other *checks* for overflow.

Since it changes the emitted IL, it has to apply.

---

E.g. this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        int k;
        checked
        {
            k = i + j;
        }
        unchecked
        {
            k = i + j;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Emits this IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 num,
        [1] int32 num2,
        [2] int32 num3)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0002: stloc.0 
    L_0003: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0004: stloc.1 
    L_0005: nop 
    L_0006: ldloc.0 
    L_0007: ldloc.1 

    L_0008: add.ovf 

    L_0009: stloc.2 
    L_000a: nop 
    L_000b: nop 
    L_000c: ldloc.0 
    L_000d: ldloc.1 

    L_000e: add 

    L_000f: stloc.2 
    L_0010: nop 
    L_0011: call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
    L_0016: pop 
    L_0017: ret 
}
```

Where you can see the two different instructions emitted.

Comment: Yes, I know how checked/unchecked works. I just want to know whether it is guaranteed to affect in the same way methods generated for lambdas in (un)checked context.

Comment: @EugenePodskal - then I've misunderstood the confusion. I could understand the confusion if someone was thinking that `checked` was, say, like a `try`/`catch` that hid overflow exceptions; that is it was implemented at runtime and thus mattered that the code in the lambda wasn't executing in the same *temporal scope* as the `checked` block.

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps best to think of C# as having two sets of integer operators, one of which performs overflow checking and one of which doesn't; whether the "+" operator binds to the "overflow-checked addition" operator or the "wrapping addition" addition operator is controlled by whether it appears within a checked or unchecked context.  The only way in which the operators affect program execution is by selecting which operators get bound to tokens like "+"; such binding takes place when the code is examined by the compiler--not when it is run.