# Secure Libraries for ASP.NET web applications

Tags: c++, asp.net, security, web

Does anyone know of any security libraries for ASP.NET web applications?

I am looking for libraries that provide basic authentication, logging into accounts, protection against SQL injection and cross-site scripting, input validation, encyrption and the like.

I have come across a library called Rhino Security.  Does anyone know of any similar libraries?

Edit:

An example of another library is CryptoSharp http://www.9rays.net/Category/63-cryptosharp.aspx

Comment: Please see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954970/best-way-to-handle-integer-overflow-in-c

Comment: @Steve Strokes I mentioned the SafeInt library as an example only.  I am looking for secure libraries for ASP.NET web applications.  The SafeInt library and Strsafe.h library are just there to serve as an example of what I am looking for.

Comment: I am looking for secure libraries for ASP.NET web applications that can provide authentication, cryptography, protection against SQL injection, input validation etc.

Comment: I know that .NET offers a lot of these features out of the box.  I am asking if there are secure libraries which improve upon these features.

Comment: You should update the question to be more related to injection and other web-based security issues since it's a little misleading right now.

Comment: An example of a security library I am looking for is called Rhino Security.  I asked this question to see if anyone knows of any similar libraries.

Comment: @Garret Vlieger Thanks.  I will do it in a moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Enterprise Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx