# Summation of positive values of integer list become negative?

Tags: c#

i have a list of integer in which i m storing RGB values of an image but after storing the sum of the values in integer then it become negative while all the values in array is positive nd this is the code!

```
        Bitmap bi = new Bitmap(@"E:\Store Signature Data\01\01_1.bmp");
        bi = ResizeImage(bi, 20, 20);

        Color[,] imgary = new Color[bi.Width, bi.Height];


        for (int x = 0; x < bi.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bi.Height; y++)
            {
                imgary[x, y] = bi.GetPixel(x, y);
            }
        }

        List<int> RGB = new List<int>();
        int c = 0;
        //RGB value= Red + (Green*256) + (Blue*256*256)
        for (int i = 0; i <20; i++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++)
            {
                c++;
                Console.WriteLine(imgary[i,a]+"  "+c);
                Color Pixels = imgary[i, a];
                int Red = Pixels.R;
                int Blue = Pixels.B;
                int Green = Pixels.G;
                 RGB.Add(Red + (Green * 256) + (Blue * 256 * 256));

            }
        }


        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < RGB.Count; i++)
        {
            total += Math.Abs(RGB[i]);
        }
        Math.Abs(total);
        Console.WriteLine(total);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show relevant code as a plain text? Maybe there is an integer overflow? Try to define your `total` which type has a wider range than `int`, like `long`, and see what happens.

Comment: Is the sum bigger than 2^32-1? That is the max int value and after exceeding that, the number wraps and becomes the min int value. If so, try using a long instead of an int.

Comment: integer max value is 2,147,483,647, you overflow it

Comment: thanks u ! my problem resolved after changing from integer to long!

Answer (score 1):

You insert 20 * 20 = 400 `RGB` values into your list. So let's say each of them would be blue. You would add 400 times `0xFF0000`. The resulting sum would be `0x18FFFFE70`, but an (32bit) `int` can take `0x7FFFFFFF` as maximum value. The first bit (`0x80000000`) indicates the sign of the value.

Since your sum overflows the `int` (by using it's first bit), the resulting sum can be negative.

If you know there will be no more than the 400 values, consider using an `Int64`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `int` is being assigned a value which is higher than the accepted maximum in C# `(2,147,483,647)`, which causes it to overflow to a negative value.

Check these questions - they may be useful:

[No overflow exception for int in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056445/no-overflow-exception-for-int-in-c)

[Best way to handle Integer overflow in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954970/best-way-to-handle-integer-overflow-in-c)