# Int64 resulting a false result, why?

Tags: c#, int

I don't seem to find *accurate result* in arithmetic operation using `Int64` var. I need to do *average* of two `Int64` values.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Int64 avg
    int testCase = 0;
    testCase = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < testCase; i++)
    {
        string[] str = Console.ReadLine().Split();

        avg = ( ( Int64.Parse( str[0] ) + Int64.Parse( str[1] ) ) / 2 );

        Console.WriteLine(avg);
    }
}
```

Input: `str[0] == 9082296538332151448` `str[1] == 5601337573664003844`

Output: `-1881554980856698162`

Why it's resulting in negative number. Trying to find the average

Comment: `9082296538332151448 + 5601337573664003844 > Int64.MaxValue`, you have integer overflow.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what input you provide? If I provide just one of those two numbers, it throws OverflowException as 9082296538332151448 cannot fit into an int. Additionally, the code won't compile as you're missing a semicolon after `Int64 avg` which makes me worry that the code in the question is not your real code. Can you post a [mcve] that doesn't rely on user input but hardcodes the input instead?

Comment: some info here:  https://chodounsky.net/2014/01/22/arithmetic-overflow-in-c-number/

Comment: Note that `(9082296538332151448m + 5601337573664003844m) / 2 == 7341817055998077646`; `Decimal` has enough precision for this. Note however that even `Decimal`'s precision is not unlimited -- for more you can switch to `BigInteger`.

Comment: semicolon missing must have removed it when posting. sorry for the mistake. apart from that, number that you tried in Int will not fit unless one uses Int64 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to handle Integer overflow in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954970/best-way-to-handle-integer-overflow-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

You have *integer overflow*:

```
9082296538332151448 + 5601337573664003844 > Int64.MaxValue
```

i.e.

```
14683634111996155292 > 9223372036854775807
```

you can use [checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) keyword in order to *throw exception* (`ArithmeticException`) in such a case (and know that something *went wrong*):

```
avg = checked( ( Int64.Parse( str[0] ) + Int64.Parse( str[1] ) ) / 2 );
```

If both `str[0]` and `str[1]` are guaranteed to be equal or under `Int64.MaxValue` you can put it as

```
Int64 arg1 = Int64.Parse(str[0]);
Int64 arg2 = Int64.Parse(str[1]); 

arg = checked(arg1 / 2 + arg2 / 2 + (arg1 % 2 + arg2 % 2) / 2);
```

In *general case* it can be something like this:

```
Int64[] data = ... 

Int64 average = 0;
Int64 rem = 0;

foreach (var item in data) {
  rem     += item % data.Length;
  average += item / data.Length + rem / data.Lenth;
  rem     %= data.Lenth; 
}   

if (rem > data.Length % 2L)
  average += 1;
else if (-rem > data.Length % 2L)
  average -= 1;
```

Finally, another (slower but universal) possibility is to use `BigInteger`s instead of `Int64`:

```
using System.Numerics;

...

avg = (Int64)( ( BigInteger.Parse( str[0] ) + BigInteger.Parse( str[1] ) ) / 2 );
```

Comment: in such case how do i use arithmetic operation in two long.MaxValue ?

Comment: @iamin_hridoy: average of two `long.MaxValue` is `( long.MaxValue / 2 +  long.MaxValue / 2 + (long.MaxValue % 2 +  long.MaxValue % 2) / 2)`